# What should we call our chatroom?

Tags: discussion, chat

Our [general discussion chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/science-fiction-fantasy) is called “Science Fiction & Fantasy”. That's kind of boring. How about a better name?

---

Aside: we also have an [SF topic of the day chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1056/sf-topic-of-the-day), where we propose a short phrase and reply with works on that topic. (We've just started; we've had topics like “interpretative dance” and “going green”.) The idea is to propose a new topic once a day or so, but chat days are clearly longer than Earth days. It's kind of dead right now — please drop in and offer suggestions!

Comment: Are we any closer to making a decision here? Let's just pick one. We can always change it if someone comes up with a better name.

Comment: What was the reasoning behind not choosing the highest voted answer?

Comment: @TonyMeyer *Mos Eisley* was tied for winner at the time we picked the name, see the [chat transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=2120547#2120547). We did say we might reconsider but never did. Well, I still prefer the other tied winner (the current winner, *The Ansible*), but have we grown fond of the current name?

Comment: @Gilles it was confusing because less than 24 hours after the change (when I commented), it was nowhere near tied.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/3y4h59/what_should_the_first_city_on_mars_be_called/cyaft2g

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**[Mos Eisley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mos_Eisley)**

*"A wretched hive of scum and villainy!"*

Answer (score 5):

And just after posting, I think of a name…

### [The ansible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansible)

Answer (score 3):

**Ten Forward**

Because it's just as geeky with Star Trek

Answer (score -1):

*The Mothership*

A nice and generic sci-fi term.

Answer (score -3):

**Compu-Global-Hyper-Mega-Net**

Suggested by Jack B Nimble

Answer (score -4):

**The Dragon's Head**

It just seems appropriate, for some reason...

Answer (score -4):

### The [Dirac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quincunx_of_Time#Plot_introduction)

Better known for its appearance in *[Cities in Flight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cities_in_Flight)*

More appropriate than the [ansible](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/751/what-should-we-call-our-chatroom/752#752), since a Dirac broadcasts whereas an ansible is usually for point-to-point communication. But the ansible is much better known, having become genericized (so to speak), whereas the Dirac is specifically by Blish.

Answer (score -4):

### The [White Hart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_from_the_White_Hart)

Hard to believe this hadn't been proposed yet!

Answer (score -5):

**The Shadowy Corner**

Granted, it's more fantasy, but in most stories, it's the guy in the shadowy corner who has all the info to help you move the plot along.

Answer (score -7):

### Draco's Tavern

OK, the particular reference is to science fiction, but the use of a bar or other drinking establishment for general meeting of strange people is broadly present in fantasy as well.

Comment: Tavern is rather generic on Stack Exchange, because it's the name of the main room on [so] ([The SO Tavern](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5/the-so-tavern-general)) and [metase] (the [Tavern on the Meta](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/89/tavern-on-the-meta)).