# What to name our new main chat room (or keep it as it is)

Tags: discussion, chat

[We have recently lost our "main" chat room, Mos Eisley](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10914/21267). But that's ok, [we have a new one](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10916/21267):

### [The Restaurant at the End of the Universe](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe).

Given that this was created by an individual, and in the spirit of community consensus, my question is **What should we name our new general chat room?**

In addition, **what should the chat feeds' names be?**

---

**Please note:** "Mos-Eisley" (or any derivative of that) is specifically excluded for obvious reasons.

<sup>Here are some historical discussions we've had on this topic:</sup>

- [What should we call our chatroom?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/751/what-should-we-call-our-chatroom)
- [Do we like the name of our chatroom?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1173/do-we-like-the-name-of-our-chatroom)
- [Primary Chatroom Name Polling](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5329/primary-chatroom-name-polling?noredirect=1)
- [Putting it all behind us - Renaming the Chatroom](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7525/putting-it-all-behind-us-renaming-the-chatroom?noredirect=1)

Comment: I'm not personally against the name, just want to make sure everyone has a say. I applaud @SQB's initiative in getting the room going and coming up with a fairly decent related name.

Comment: Can I add, any suggestions please consider the feed names to be related. Although Mos had Obie-related names, the new room has THGTTG related names and it would be nice if any suggestions followed suit.

Comment: I am Lobbying for Marvin, it is the best choice after all :) See my answer

Comment: One possibility (which I also raised on [this now-deleted meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10971/31394)): we could set up a few *different* chatrooms named after different franchises. We already have Doctor Who and American Gods rooms, and there have been Star Wars and Harry Potter rooms in the past. Like SO has a Python room and a C++ room and whatever. I seem to recall Shog saying somewhere that SFF chat has got to the size where a single main chatroom isn't enough any more.

Answer (score 25):

Leave it as is, I'm happy with the name:

### The Restaurant at the End of the Universe

Answer (score 22):

## Ten Forward

Clearly, the last room was too much of a wretched hive of scum and villainy.  So let's name our room after that more civilized establishment from that other major sci-fi franchise — a place where anyone can go to let their hair down and enjoy their beverage of choice without hassle.

## Corresponding suggested feed names...

- **Wesley** (main site feed) — ***Shut up, Wesley!***
- **Memory Beta** (meta feed)
- **Red Alert** (featured posts)
- **Intruder Alert** (Movies & TV)

Comment: (I'd actually prefer `Net Backward`, but that's just me...

Comment: Ideas for Feed names?

Comment: @Edlothiad : Yep, they're there (between the two videos).

Comment: What about the lit feed? These are cool though!

Comment: "Shut up, Wesley!" is a nice touch.

Comment: Other than "Intruder Alert" for M&TV, I like this. Let's not create any more bad feeling between the two sites by calling M&TV posts "intruders" :-)

Comment: I might suggest quadrant names for the feeds. like Gamma or Delta Quadrant for M&TV.

Answer (score 16):

I'd really prefer something that's less of a mouthful! What about

### Milliways (The Restaurant at the End of the Universe)

[Milliways](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/Milliways) is the actual name of the restaurant, and it's easy to say *and* type when referring to it shorthand.

The "The Restaurant at the End of the Universe" could also just go in the room description, but it's not necessary.

It was also suggested during the last time we tried to rename the room, so legacy bonus?

Comment: TREU! it is easier to say

Comment: @Edlothiad "What's the acronym?" "It's _not_ TRUE"

Comment: The Restaurant at the End of the Universe, it was a pun that it couldn't be shortened to TREU which is even easier than Milliways, but still pretend I was agreeing with you with a typo. Clearly went sideways very quickly

Comment: @Edlothiad My response is technically accurate and in jest. The acronym is _not_ TRUE, it's TREU.

Comment: Oh haha I didn't see the speech marks :P

Comment: "Mos" was so easy to say... "TRatEotU" is not. Milliways is better.

Comment: I prefer the other. I’ll grant the advantage that this is a bit easier to type, but many people just went with “chat” anyway. In particular, I like the immediate sci-fi feel that we get from “The Restaurant at the End of the Universe,” which “Milliways” doesn’t convey. I think “chat” or “TREU” or “the Restaurant” works for shorthand.

Comment: @Catija TREU, "Mos" was easy to say!

Comment: This one gives me a nice Happy Days feeling. *Sunday, Monday, Milliways! Tuesday, Wednesday, Milliways! Thursday, Friday, Milliways! Saturday, what a day, geekin' all week with you!*

Answer (score 11):

### The current name is fine

**The Restaurant at the End of the Universe** is fine. While it can't satisfy fans of all science fiction and fantasy franchises, the same was true of our previous chat room, and people were generally fine with the name.

In addition, it has a definite sci-fi feel even to those not familiar with the source material: "at the end of the Universe."

More important than the name of the room is that it learns from the mistakes of the previous one.

Comment: ...And all of the feeds are already named after HHGttG characters.

Answer (score 7):

[I've now posted the proposal as it's own question.](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10971/quarterly-chat-name-rotation-q4-2017), go there to submit your names/vote.

I had a proposal in chat that went over pretty well, so I was asked to submit it here.

My idea is to make the chat room a [holodeck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holodeck) of sorts, and periodically change the name/feeds to represent some of the varying fanbases we have in the community.

For example, on something like a quarterly basis we could change the name around categories such as:

- Star Trek
- Game of Thrones/A Song of Ice and Fire
- Harry Potter
- Comic books
- Lord of the Rings
- Doctor Who

Essentially adding a flavor to the room. To me, it also makes it thematically match our stack.

Changing the name/feeds is somewhat of a trivial process, and the link to the room would stay the same so long as the room name is removed, leaving only the room #:

- http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/

If people like this general idea, then we can make another meta for the details of implementing it and choosing the rotation.

Comment: You don't have to remove or change the room name in the link - the only relevant part is the room number try [Planet Krypton](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/planet-krypton) or [Milliways](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/milliways) - they all work.

Comment: Or how about, "The Holodeck". Yeah.

Comment: A cool idea. Logistically though, after about 6-7 quarters or rotations, you'll start to venture into some of the more obscure or at least not so famous canons; so where will we go after the likes of Star Wars / Trek? Also, renaming the room often(ish) will not allow people to get as emotionally attached to the room, thereby not having as much ownership over it.

Answer (score 2):

### Planet Krypton

*No, not the one that exploded!*

Planet Krypton is a supehero-themed restaurant seen most notably in *Kingdon Come*:

[image] [image]
<sub>Click for full resolution</sub>

In line with the whole superhero tradition, it features ridiculously dressed staff, and ridiculous names that are spoofs of ridiculous superhero names, e.g. "[Starro](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Starro) the Casserole", "[Mxyzptlk](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Mister_Mxyzptlk) Mozarella Sticks", "[Power Girl](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Power_Girl) Chicken Sandwich" (the cut is the breast), and "Man of Beef".

Feed names could be in line with those, but I don't have any ideas (yet).

Comment: But it's with a K, even in the comic, you can see the K on the menus and signage.

Comment: @CreationEdge _shhhh_, you didn't see that :) Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

### House on the Rock

[image]

It's a [real location](http://%20https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_on_the_Rock), a slightly fictional version of which was featured in Neil Gaiman's [*American Gods*](http://americangods.wikia.com/wiki/House_on_the_Rock).

It's a roadside tourist attraction where the Old Gods meet for their war council.

[image]

Feed names could be

- **Media** - for Movies & TV
- **Mr. Ibis** - for our meta
- **Mad Sweeney** - for featured posts
- *[TBD]* - for main site feed

Comment: Just throwing in some ideas.

Comment: But I even have feed names....

Comment: The current name is better (yeah, even with me), but have an upvote, you just look too terribly lonely down here for a not bad suggestion.

Comment: @Radhil thanks ^_^

Answer (score 1):

The *Restaurant* is a bit banal, shouldn't we look for something a bit less obvious?

For example

## Jackson's Whole

Which is a planetary equivalent of Mos Eisley by also being a 'wretched hive of scum and villainy'.

But if we want something more popular then there is

## Serenity

The members of which, not unlike those in the previous incarnations of the SFF chatrooms want to continue to travel and have fun together, but are othen messing up and clashing with the authorities?  And speaking of Whedon's creations there's also the

## Cabin in the Woods

Comment: I like and appreciate the suggestions, the only thing is that people seem to be trying to shed the "scum and villainy" reputation :)

Answer (score -1):

**Name:** The Restaurant at the End of the Universe.

For all the reason already given.

**"In addition, what should the chat feeds' names be?"**

**Feed Name:** Marvin, Marvin is a Robot that has a brain the size of a planet.  I can not think of a single character in HHGTG world, well other than Prax That would be more suitable for the feed.

**Marvin The Paranoid Android**

> Marvin the Paranoid AndroidMarvin was made by the Sirius Cybernetics
>   Corporation, and is a prototype robot with the new GPP feature.
>
> He's incredibly smart. Through very odd circumstances involving
>   time-travel, he is thirty-seven times older than the universe itself.
>
> In all that time, the diodes down his left side, which cause him pain,
>   were never replaced.
>
> He's very depressed.

Prax: I wanted to find the section that defines him, it was in The chat room searched that and could not find it. So a little help would be nice :)

Comment: Why do we need three answers all saying the same thing?

Comment: Because the Feed Name was included and I could not see a reasonable way to force the other two use my Feed Name? :)  Just wanted to make sure I had Bolded the "Feed Name" header and point it out to you just in case you didn't read it :)

Answer (score -3):

Just a thought I had:

### The Leaky Cauldron

Another possibility is

### Diagon Alley

with feed names like "Flourish and Blotts," "Ollivander's," etc.

Comment: Names of Feeds?

Comment: Ollivander for main feeds. Madam Rosmerta for the Meta feeds. Hedwig for any other feeds.

Comment: What about Featured Feeds? Hedwig too?