# Why is the name of main chat room "Mos Eisley"?

Tags: support, chat

The most active chat room of SciFi.SE is [Mos Eisley](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley) which has a tagline `General discussion for http://scifi.stackexchange.com`. Googling the words returns that Mos Eisley is  a spaceport on the planet Tatooine (Star Wars universe). Why is the chat room named after it? Any specific reason?

Comment: Because we're a wretched hive of scum and villany.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the time, it was the most highly voted name, albeit by not very much. See [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/751/98).

Comment: And the [followup question](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1173/1234) never seemed to reach a clear consensus.

Comment: Actually, it tied for the highest votes, and Gilles chose from those two without explaining why that one (possibly because his suggestion was the other, to avoid the appearance of favouritism).  Within hours (minutes?) the alternative was higher voted, but it's much harder to change something than put it in place originally.

Comment: @TonyMeyer That's exactly it.