# Should we rename our chatroom? (yes/no)

Tags: discussion, chat

### TL;DR:

I'm aware of [this recent similar meta question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7525/19561), but I think it's a flawed question, since it seems to be asking both *if* we should do so and *what* the new name should be.

**This question is *just* for voting yes or no.**
*(And thus not a duplicate).*

### Should we rename our main chatroom?

As we're all aware of, we've [had some problems](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7588/19561) in [our main chatroom](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7517/19561). In the wake of those problems, the question was posed [whether we should rename our chatroom](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7525/19561), *[Mos Eisley](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198)*, to make a clean break with its troublesome past.

Unfortunately, that question got clogged by a great number of suggestions for a new name, making it impossible to get a clear answer on whether *we should rename it at all*.

So this question is an attempt to get an answer to the question that should be answered first:

**Should we rename our main chatroom?**

Please do not leave suggestions for new names, just vote yes or no. Only up votes will be counted, down votes on either suggestion will be ignored.

---

### Outcome

*With +24/-11 against +16/-10, the noes have it.*

Comment: Well.. Well.. Do we have chatroom rename meme yet?

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 We probably _should_.

Comment: if you really want a true yea/nay vote, you should only have one "answer" and just have people vote it up or down.

Comment: @phantom42 Or afterall just the question itself, maybe worded more as a direct feature request.

Comment: In the absence of any reported actual problem with the chatroom’s name, re-naming it seems like a “what colour shall we paint the bikeshed” issue.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite the idea was to [make a clean break](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7525/19561) with [the past](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7517/19561).

Comment: @SQB: oh I know. It’s just there’s no evidence of an actual problem. “Mos Eisley has probably acquired a bad reputation” — *[citation needed]*.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### No

We should not rename our main chatroom.

Comment: I previously threw names into the hat for fun, and if we did decide to rename then I'd have had some input,  but in second thought it's too good the way it is.

Answer (score 5):

### Yes

We should rename our main chatroom.

Answer (score 5):

## No

Not only should we not rename the chat room but which should also lock<sup>1</sup> discussions on this for one year.

This is because it is being discussed very often here and each time the answer is No. Let's use our energies to discuss something else for a time.

Here are the discussions I found (please feel free to add other duplicates):

1. [Putting it all behind us - Renaming the Chatroom](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7525/putting-it-all-behind-us-renaming-the-chatroom?lq=1)
2. [Primary Chatroom Name Polling](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5329/primary-chatroom-name-polling)
3. [Do we like the name of our chatroom?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1173/do-we-like-the-name-of-our-chatroom)
4. [What should we call our chatroom?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/751/what-should-we-call-our-chatroom) *(original question)*

And for completeness:

- [Why is the name of main chat room "Mos Eisley"?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2533/why-is-the-name-of-main-chat-room-mos-eisley?lq=1)

Perceptive people might spot a [conflict of interest](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/769/143) on my part but I don't think that is my motivation: I just want to stop discussing it! And, I don't believe that people's behaviour would change even if we renamed it *"My Little Pony: Sweetness and Light"*.

<sub>1 By which I mean *close any questions raising this topic as a duplicate*.</sub>

Comment: Actually, that is why I asked this question. I'd like to see a definitive answer, instead of 40+ suggestions for a new name.

Comment: "it is being discussed very often here" -- it was asked once, and then re-asked more clearly a second time *a week* later. It's been brought up a total of 4 separate times in four *years*. That's what you call "very often"?

Comment: @MikeEdenfield: well, it has been discussed often recently. Frankly I think more than once is too often...

Comment: I'm with Mike, asking five times in four years is not a big deal. Especially when the only reason the fifth question (this one) exists is because the fourth question was really two different questions that were not properly separated. And the only reason the fourth one exists is because something very bad happened in the chatroom recently, which was not the case in any previous discussion.

Comment: May I kindly request to remove your answer? My aim here was to have a concise and clear poll, with just two possible answers. Now, with two options for _no_, the waters get muddied again.

Comment: @SQB Polls like this are a poor fit for Meta. When answers completely lack reasoning, they're not particularly compelling, nor do they provide future guidance.

Comment: @SQB - I'll leave it unless multiple users request I delete it. Since any user (with sufficient rep) can up or down vote any question or answer, voting on this answer does not exclude voting on any other answer. So I don't see how it muddies the waters.

Comment: I'm with @SQB here: this was supposed to be a simple yes/no poll, and a third answer just confuses things.