# Primary Chatroom Name Polling

Tags: discussion, voting

Please, add a new option as answer (Don't Repeat.. So, please read all answers first). The answer with largest vote would be chosen (this can be checked from time to time in the end of each month). Please, participate.

Comment: I'm unconvinced we need a change of name. What benefit would accrue from doing so?

Comment: @Richard Believe in democracy... Mos Eisley is also an option.

Comment: [What](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/751/what-should-we-call-our-chatroom)? [This](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2533/why-is-the-name-of-main-chat-room-mos-eisley?lq=1) [again](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1173/do-we-like-the-name-of-our-chatroom)?

Comment: Seriously, why all the hate at Sachin??? He asked a valid question, and you can't use the excuse "on Meta downvotes are about disagreeing" **because the question didn't express an opinion to disagree with** (he even posted "Mos Eisley" as the answer). And the question is perfectly valid since the topic was clearly discussed and broached by several users in the chatroom yesterday.

Comment: @Wikis - site population changed. Opinions changed. It's perfectly valid to re-poll the names as a new question, since the answers on old ones may no longer be valid.

Comment: @DVK: 1. Not everybody is a chat completionist, and so if there was discussion about maybe changing the name, that should have been mentioned or linked in the question. 2. Implicit in the question is the idea that the chat name should be changed. I downvoted because I don’t think we need a name change. If you could link the relevant transcripts, I'd consider reversing my vote.

Comment: @alexwlchan - that's my point. The question did NOT imply that the name needs to be changed, and as proof, the same user posted the current name as one of the options as an answer (and alluded to in immediate comment). So if you don't want name changed, the correct action is to **upvote that answer**, not to downvote the question.

Comment: @DVK: That wasn’t the impression I got from reading the question, but I see your point.

Comment: @DVK: nice of you to stand up for Sachin but I don't think it was a personal issue at all. There was no reference to the recent chat conversation so it seemed like one user was suggesting a name change (again) without any justification. But, as alexwlchan mentioned, with the context some downvotes might be reversed.

Comment: @DVK - He wasn't terribly polite about those people who voted for the status quo "*Voting for existing one would be your Inertia. Think Again*"

Comment: @Richard Those words aren't gunpoint. One can still vote it.

Comment: @Richard - ever heard "vote for the post, not the user"?

Comment: @DVK - I didn't like the suggestion either, which was a happy coincidence :-)

Comment: Note that the "results" of this poll are highly suspect since many peoples' votes have probably been reversed:  http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/5359/4167

Comment: @Ward not reversed, but wiped, right (me too)? So basically any answer of Sachin's, including the status quo, could have had any number of additional down votes (or up votes, I guess, although that seems less likely for this question).

Answer (score 7):

Mos Eisley

................................

Comment: Voting for existing one would be your Inertia. Think Again.

Answer (score 2):

In the [previous poll](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/751/what-should-we-call-our-chatroom), **The Ansible** was the runner-up.

Interestingly, it's now the highest voted with a mighty +4.

Comment: [Ansible is taken](http://ansible.uk/).

Answer (score 0):

TARDIS

..............................

Comment: Love it! This chatroom is bigger on the inside than the outside...

Answer (score -1):

Delphic Expanse

..............................

Answer (score -1):

Time Vortex

.............................

Answer (score -1):

I'd prefer something vaguely sci-fi/fantasy sounding, but generic enough to not be tied to a specific universe:

#### The Void

Comment: And it may also be where our one-winged angel in the banner is going to/coming from

Answer (score -2):

Hogwarts

..............................

Answer (score -2):

Gallifrey

..............................

Answer (score -2):

S.H.I.E.L.D.

..............................

Answer (score -2):

Skynet

.................................

Answer (score -2):

I don't think the chatroom name should be changed. But if it was to change, my favorite proposal is

### The Dirac

The Dirac is a communication medium in James Blish's series [*Cities in Flight*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cities_in_Flight). It is nowhere as well-known as Ursula K. Le Guin's [ansible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansible) (I don't remember any other author calling their communication device a Dirac), but it's more appropriate: an ansible is a point-to-point communication device, like a personal messaging system, whereas the Dirac instantly broadcasts all messages all over the universe, like a chatroom.

Comment: Shuldn't this be split into 2 separate answers? I want to upvote the "no change" part, and downvote "Dirac" because I think that there are names I like better.

Comment: @DVK If you want no change, downvote the question and upvote the [Mos Eisley answer](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/5330).

Comment: agree on #2, fully disagree on #1. The question did NOT advocate for **changing** the name, just asked what it should be in a neutral way.

Answer (score -3):

USS Enterprise

..............................

Answer (score -4):

Death Star

..............................

Comment: My Fav. If Star Wars is popular here, this popular weapon should be the choice.

Answer (score -4):

I think it needs to be something that conveys "chat room".

**Ten Forward** was the alt name.

Answer (score -4):

[The Billiards Club](http://www.revolutionsf.com/fiction/ourdistantcousins/01.html)

Answer (score -7):

[The Three Broomsticks](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Three_Broomsticks_Inn)

Comment: If anything, it should be "Hog's Head"

Answer (score -8):

> Rivendell

or

> Imladris

(the Last Homely House :-D )

Answer (score -9):

I like what Mos Eisley conveys, but here's a suggestion that's closer to something real:

**Stan Lee's back porch**

Because who wouldn't want to share a beer with Stan Lee on his back porch and talk about SciFi.

Comment: Well... I wouldn't :) So it's not as obvious as you think. Also, not every site user is a comics fan.

Comment: @DVK You don't have to be a comics fan to appreciate the creative mind of Stan Lee. Likewise, you don't have to be a rap fan (as I am not) to appreciate the poetic nature of Eminem's lyrics (as i do).

Comment: @DVK Not every user is a Star Wars fan.

Comment: true, but there's a lot more people who know what Mos Eisley is than who recognize the name of Stan Lee.

Comment: @DVK I challenge that. Stan Lee, especially today with the Marvel franchise as used by Disney, is far more well known than he was in decades past. The name of an obscure Star Wars town is something that I think only SW fans would know.

Comment: Do Marvel films actually mention his name in any reasonably prominent way that an average film goer would notice?

Comment: @DVK At least half the articles about/announcing those films start with a line like "Adaptation of Stan Lee's ..." He also tends to cameo in them.

Comment: Maybe the problem here is that you just don't care for beer ;)

Comment: @DVK So I guess we've both surmised that Stan Lee is primarily only known by comics fans and Mos Eisley primarily by SW fans. The question now is who has more fans. Comics, in total, or SW? Is that on-topic on the main site?

Comment: I would say it should be ontopic, but I'm not always supported by "close anything but simple trivia and story-ID question" brigades, so don't use my opinion as basis :)

Comment: @DVK After drafting, it seems off-topic. [I posted to chat.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19340261#19340261)