# Putting it all behind us - Renaming the Chatroom

Tags: discussion, chat

As everyone must be aware by now, there have been a LOT of problems recently in our primary chatroom, [Mos Eisley](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198), culminating in the room being frozen and some of our most active users being temporarily suspended. Other people have already posted on meta about why this came about and what kind of behaviour needs to be addressed in order to stop it happening again. I'm not going to rehash those issues; this post is about how we can try to *put it all behind us*.

Mos Eisley has probably acquired a bad reputation across the network by now for its constant flags and fights. Assuming that such events aren't going to keep on happening in the future, it would be nice to distance ourselves from the past craziness, so that people don't think "oh, Mos Eisley - that's full of jerks" as soon as they see the room and need to be persuaded otherwise.

Getting to the point ... how about we **rename the chatroom** once it's reopened? Much better to have people come to the chatroom with no prejudices, and then by the time they realise it's the former Mos Eisley, they may already have realised we're an OK bunch :-)

<sub>*And yes, I know this proposal has been [made before](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5329/primary-chatroom-name-polling) with scant success, but there's a better reason for it now!*</sub>

Comment: Interesting idea. But how about anything *not* from a specific property? (Unfortunately I have no specific ideas other than that general one, though.)

Comment: @TARS Excellent idea (I don't know Star Wars, some others don't know Doctor Who, there are probably some who don't know Harry Potter, etc.). I'll try to think of something. If you come up with anything specific, do post an answer!

Comment: how about just *The Local Pub* then

Comment: This seems completely pointless. Is anyone going to come to Mos Eisley and say, "oh, this is Mos Eisley, I remember all those arguments here, so I should start a new one"?

Comment: @phantom42 I'm not thinking of people starting a new one; I'm thinking of people not wanting to come to chat at all. Some of our high-rep users have already drifted away from Mos because of the unpleasantness. There are probably a lot of chatters from other sites who dislike Mos Eisley too.

Comment: *Around The Hearth*

Comment: If people have drifted away because of the tone of the chat room what makes you think that changing the name will change that?

Comment: @phantom42 From the question: "Much better to have people come to the chatroom with no prejudices, and then by the time they realise it's the former Mos Eisley, they may already have realised we're an OK bunch"

Comment: oh, so we're trying to trick people. got it.

Comment: @phantom42 It's the ol' bait and switch!

Comment: Mos Eisley was *"[a wretched hive of scum and villany](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/751/what-should-we-call-our-chatroom/769#769)"*. Just sayin' :)

Comment: And, yes, [renaming Mos Eisley](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5329/primary-chatroom-name-polling?lq=1#comment14472_5329) is becoming [meme](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1289/the-many-memes-of-scifi-stackexchange) here. ;)

Comment: @Wikis: right, so the temporary solution is the Mos Eisley Cantina, which is full of bar brawls: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/31550/mos-eisley-cantina

Comment: I don't quite understand the point of this post from the OP. You ask a question about renaming the chatroom but then provide an answer saying we shouldn't change it. Which is your opinion? :-)

Comment: @user35594 I provided several answers to be voted on. I realised that some people would want to keep the old name, so I posted that as an answer to save them the trouble. Personally my favourite would be either "the TARDIS" or "Rivendell", but I'm only one user in the community.

Comment: I disagree with a need to change the room's name, but if we were going to, I'd be up for [**The Ansible**](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/752/21267)

Comment: @Mooz Post it as an answer?

Comment: I don't get how this voting is supposed to work now. Votes for the question mean "Yes, change it", but then there's an answer that's specifically "No, don't change it" which means people are downvoting the question, upvoting that answer, and downvoting all the other answers. It's heavily skewed the results, and now they're almost useless. And the number of upvotes on the question don't even match those on the "let's keep it answer", which is even more unhelpful!

Comment: "I don't think the name should be changed" and "I don't like this name" are two separate and valid votes, even by the same  user.

Comment: @phantom42 It couples together 2 separate issues. We're seeing a really unusual number of downvotes, in the "sink the other options to the bottom" instead of a "bring the best to the top" style, that's typically not seen. People against the change will downvote everything, but people *for* the change aren't likely to upvote everything, because that's atypical behavior. So we've got 1 post with 2 distinct polls sharing tangled votes biased towards a single result. I don't care one way or another about the name change, but this current poll is nothing more than a farce.

Comment: which is why using meta answers to conduct a poll isn't a good way to do this.

Comment: Perhaps it makes sense to say that **if the question has a positive score, then people are in favour of renaming it** and in that case, the highest-scored non-Mos Eisley option wins?

Comment: @randal'thor But the Mos Eisley option has a higher score than the question itself, and more total votes.

Comment: upvotes on the question do not necessarily mean that the users agree it should be changed; the voter may just think it's a valid discussion. they may also just still prefer the current name, or not like any of the proposed new ones.

Comment: NOTE to Everyone: if you dislike several of the suggestions, be careful about downvoting.  If you downvote several suggestions from the same user, your votes will likely be reversed automatically.

Comment: Because Tolkien, Harry Potter, Game of Thrones, etc., are so popular: **"The Magic Gathering"**   :)   ⁠

Comment: 1) A rose by any other name is still a rose.  If we don't change the behavior that's causing the problem, no name change will work.  If we do change it, it should be AFTER the issues have been solved.  2) I've seen, many times, how a name or title can color how people think of themselves, a business, or place.  If we do change it, it should be to something with a positive reputation, a place where proper behavior and respect is expect.

Comment: @Tango Totally agreed with 1); the whole premise of the question is that this behaviour WILL change. And does 2) mean you support my renaming idea? I'm glad someone does! :-)

Comment: @Ward I'm not sure if the vote reversal script applies to Meta posts, since there's no reputation changes involved. If it *is* active on Meta, then it's not limited to downvotes; upvoting several answers by the same user may be seen as suspicious too.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist It does apply to Meta posts: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5357/bug-votes-not-being-recorded/5359#5359

Comment: @randal'thor: I'm not sure, right now, just who I agree with on this.  Maybe with you.  Or maybe if we renamed it something with a positive connotation, it might start subtly influencing people's behavior.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist  It does apply here, it undid a bunch of my votes on the answers here yesterday.  The same thing happened last time SS did a poll question about renaming the chat room.

Comment: Are we going to get this call to change the name of Mos Eisley repeatedly until the guys proposing the change finally win the vote? Here's another suggestion: from my brief visits to the chatroom, it seems there are always the same few people in there; I assume any trouble must be caused by a subset of them (since there seldom is anyone else in there). Ban them all from chat (those who are not mods, I guess) and *that* would bring about a more real change than simply changing the name.

Comment: @Tango Mos Eisley has negative connotations? Listen, I wouldn't even be aware there were any problems in chat *unless* you guys kept bringing them up here in meta. I assume the majority opinion is between "nobody cares about chat" and "guys, just shut up about your infighting in chat" :) The only people at chat just have too much spare time, which isn't the norm for the majority of us!

Comment: so, your idea is "take all of the people who use the chat room, and ban them from the chat room?"

Comment: @AndresF. For the record, a subset of them *were* banned for a while. Notice this very post says "some of our most active users being temporarily suspended". I think the mods/CMs had reached the same conclusion you just did, and from what I can tell (whether or not it was "fair" or "justified") it's already having an effect.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield Well, it would surely bring about a more real change than simply renaming the chatroom and keeping the same people that are causing trouble. Also, either option (renaming or banning) would probably have minimal impact, since I'm betting most of us regular users don't care all that much about chat. I'm guessing the Powers That Be simply think that having too much fighting in chat reflects badly on the main site.

Comment: @AndresF.: Back off on the "you guys."  I haven't had issues in chat and I have not been bringing them up.  I have participated in some of the discussions, though.  So a personally directed comment is inappropriate.  But, for those that don't care about chat, this really doesn't concern them, does it?

Comment: @Tango Fair enough. My comment sounded aggressive; I apologize. As an outsider to chat, I may be overgeneralizing. I find all this infighting and discussions about chat memes and all that crap tiresome, so I may be oversensitive. And more relevant to the comment you replied to: "Mos Eisley" doesn't have negative connotations; it's well liked by Star Wars fans. A reasonable argument could be made that not all scifi fans are Star Wars fans, so Mos Eisley may not be the most encompassing name (then again, a Doctor Who-inspired name would probably be worse...). But "negative"? That's news to me...

Comment: @AndresF.: The only time Mos Eisley is described, on screen, Obi Wan says, "Never will you find a more wretched hive of scum and villainy."  I'd say that is a bad reputation.  I found, in long years of teaching (most of it in residential treatment programs) that a name or nickname can have an amazing effect on expectations and behavior.  Call a kid "klutz" for a month and see how his coordination starts failing.  The same can happen to a place: Peoples' behavior can live up or down to a name.

Comment: @Tango Oh, *come on*! It's a well-loved name by Star Wars fans. The argument here is that the name Mos Eisley has been tainted *by chat users who misbehave*, not by its in-universe reputation! As a scifi.se regular, you should be familiar with out-of-universe vs in-universe explanations, right? Well, here is a clear-cut out-of-universe one. And changing the name won't help one bit in changing the behavior of chat users. Anyway, I'm outta this discussion -- I find all this self-referential meta-obssesion cringeworthy. Back to the main site for me!

Comment: I'm familiar with in and out of universe explanations.  I'm also familiar with what I learned from years of working in psych treatment programs.  Names make a difference.  The name may be well loved, but that's also because it connotes a place of "scum and villainy."  Names create expectations, that's my point (that you bypassed), and people do start to behave in line with the expectations.  I've seen that over and over.  But, hey, we're trying to fix something and all I see from you is complaints.  If you don't like the discussion, don't take part in it and don't read it.  It's that simple.

Comment: @AndresF. -- I don't think users who chat have "too much time on their hands." Speaking for myself, I just have chat running in the background, and I check in throughout the day. Sometimes that leads to an actual conversation I can participate in, but more often than not, it actually doesn't.  Anyhow, everyone makes time for activities they enjoy, whether it's perusing the main site, answering questions, watching movies/TV, etc.  Chatting isn't any worse than that, and those who like to chat aren't aren't any more "losers" than the rest of the geeks who hang at SFF! ;)

Comment: @Slytherincess I didn't imply anyone was a loser. That would be a self-defeating comment to make in a website for scifi & fantasy nerds... such as myself :)

Comment: @AndresF. - Just so long as we both admit we're in the same Nerdmobile, it's all good :) (And, yes. That is me, admitting I'm a huge SFF nerd! :P)

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/3y4h59/what_should_the_first_city_on_mars_be_called/cyaft2g

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Mos Eisley

Renaming the chatroom won't solve any of its problems; let's leave the name as it is.

Comment: As I am an old supporter of primary chatroom renaming, -1. Yeah.

Comment: +1 Unless it can be demonstrated that the name was the proximal cause of the debacle(s), a renaming would accomplish nothing. It would be fixing the wrong problem, like painting the bathroom because there is a backed-up toilet.

Comment: @Robusto I never said the name caused anything, just that changing it *along with its users' behaviour* could help us to put it all behind us. From the OP: "Assuming that such events aren't going to keep on happening in the future, it would be nice to distance ourselves from the past craziness"

Comment: I never said you said it did. I am simply moving a little farther down an avenue you started.

Comment: The name is completely unrelated to the misbehavior of chat users.

Answer (score 12):

### The Nexus

The term "Nexus" is often used in *both* Science Fiction and Fantasy, and the name implies a connection point where we can communicate with one another.

Comment: Similar to something like *The Ether* too :)

Answer (score 3):

### Milliways    (or The Restaurant at the End of the Universe)

A tribute to the late great Douglas Adams.

Answer (score 0):

### Seems Oily

a) Because this all resulted in a sticky situation

b) It's an anagram of Mos Eisley

Comment: :-D :-D Nice one!

Answer (score 0):

We all love Mos Eisley, and I think a completely new name would be a mistake. However, I also think that not acknowledging that things need to and will change is a mistake.

As such I think the new name of our main chat room should be;

### Mos Eisley Episode IV: A New Hope

It's still Mos Eisley, but it's a new beginning, the start of a new, hopefully better era.

Comment: Nice one....... :)

Comment: lol..............

Answer (score -1):

### The Leaky Cauldron

.. ... ..... ... .. ... .. .... ... .. .. .. .... .. .. ..

Comment: Cheers to Harry Potter guys...

Answer (score -1):

Ten Forward

... .. ..... .... .. .. .. ... ...... .. ..... .... ..

Comment: Cheers to *Star Trek: The Next Generation* fans...

Answer (score -1):

Skynet

....................................................................

Comment: Cheers to Terminator fans...

Answer (score -2):

**The Inn Outside the World**

Title of a classic story by Edmond Hamilton.

Comment: ... and vaguely reminiscent of Douglas Adams' "the outside of the Asylum".

Answer (score -2):

Omega Protocol

..................................................................

Answer (score -3):

### The TARDIS

From the outside, it's just a square box on the chat.SE front page. On the inside, it's a whole universe of conversation on every topic under the sun.

Comment: (This would have my +1 for sure.)

Comment: +1. I strongly wanted this to happen the last time.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 Yay! I thought you'd be a supporter of this idea :-)

Answer (score -3):

## Rivendell

The last homely house. A place where friends can come together and discuss. Plus, [lord-of-the-rings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings) is one of the top tags and most users have some familiarity with it (like [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) or [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars)).

Answer (score -3):

### Chamber of Secrets

From [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter)

Comment: +1 ..... ..... ... .. .. .

Answer (score -3):

Time Vortex

.. .. .. .. .. ... .... .. .. .. .. ... .. .. ... .. ....

Comment: Cheers to Whovians... (I upvoted this last time too)

Answer (score -3):

Night Spot

.... ... ... .. .. ..... ..... .. ... .. ..

Comment: Cheers to Tourchwood fans....

Answer (score -3):

**Mountains of Madness**

Part of Lovecraft's famous Cthulhu Mythos

<sub>There is a nasty little pun linking the story of this book to our current situation ;)</sub>

Answer (score -3):

42

..............................................................

Well, it's the ultimate answer!

Answer (score -4):

### Madam Rosmerta's

May be this would sound less villainous and scummy? And of course, as pointed out on the other answer, [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) is our top tag beside story-ID

Comment: Let's go even further and have Madam Puddifoots Teashop!

Comment: Less well-known outside HP fandom, though. Hogwarts is a universally recognised name; Madam Rosmerta, not so much.

Comment: Mos Eiseley wouldn't be know to anyone who doesn't know Star Wars either

Answer (score -4):

### Honeydukes

The Hogsmead candy shop, so that the room can be more welcoming to the kiddies as well

Answer (score -4):

### The Hogs Head

The Mos Eisley of Potterverse

Answer (score -4):

### The Round Table

It fulfills our fantasy side whilst being popular enough that I believe almost all people will be familiar with it.

Answer (score -4):

### The Common Room

As in [hogwarts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hogwarts)

Comment: But "The Common Room" itself doesn't sound SFFy. Also, which common room? We have a whole mixture of Houses among the SFF chat regulars!

Comment: that's why it's just the common room

Comment: so it's all inclusive, no house biases

Answer (score -4):

Not that I think renaming the chatroom will solve anything, but I'll once again propose my favorite name…

### The Dirac

The Dirac is a communication medium in James Blish's series [*Cities in Flight*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cities_in_Flight) which instantly broadcasts all messages all over the universe, like a chatroom.

(While Ursula K. Le Guin's [ansible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansible) is better known, it isn't really appropriate as a chatroom name, since an ansible provides two-party communication, like a phone, not an open medium like a chatroom.)

Answer (score -4):

The Hip Joint

... .. ... ... .. ... ... ... .... .. ... ... .. .. ..

Comment: Cheers to Futurama fans...

Answer (score -4):

Maxwell's Nightclub

..... .... .. ... .... ... .. ... .. ..... .. .. .. ...

Comment: Cheers to Smallville fans..

Answer (score -4):

Mystic Grill

.... ... .... .. ... ..... ... .. .... .. .. .. ... .

Comment: Cheers to *The Vampire Diaries* fans...

Answer (score -4):

### SciFi&Fantasy Chat

Short, simple and to the point

Comment: And rather boring, to be honest.

Comment: @Wikis: It seems to me that this chatroom could do with being a little more boring.

Answer (score -4):

## Tanagra

This is the famous tale in the *TNG* episode 'Darmok' where Darmok and Jalad make peace at Tanagra!

[image]

Answer (score -4):

Death Star

............................................................

Answer (score -4):

Wait for it.... nananana nananana *CHAT-CAVE!*  We all show up to see the next episode, same chat time. Same chat channel. If we are going to change the name of the room, trust me. This is the right choice. It's the name we *deserve.* [image: Hero]

Answer (score -5):

### The Great Hall

as in [hogwarts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hogwarts) because [The Common Room](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7535/13716) was [not inclusive enough](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7525/putting-it-all-behind-us-renaming-the-chatroom#comment20555_7535)

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't inclusive enough - my main point was it doesn't sound SFFy enough! Nor does The Great Hall really.

Comment: fair enough....

Comment: I personally think Mos Eisley is fine though

Answer (score -5):

### Construct

As in [the-matrix](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-matrix) training room

Answer (score -5):

## Quark's

A different wretched hive of scum and villainy, as seen in [star-trek-ds9](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-ds9).

Answer (score -5):

**The Billiards Club**

From Lord Dunsany's Jorkens tales, like [this one](http://www.revolutionsf.com/fiction/ourdistantcousins/01.html).

Answer (score -5):

My choice is the name of the recreation room aboard the JMC mining ship [red-dwarf](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/red-dwarf), which is...

## The Recreation Room

Answer (score -6):

Fortune Casino

........ ... .. .. ... .. .. .... .... .. .... .... .

Comment: Cheers to Smallville fans...

Answer (score -6):

**The Spaceport Bar**

An iconic stfnal setting.

Answer (score -6):

## Nimbus III

The planet from *Star Trek V: The Final Frontier*.  This planet was intended to be the planet of Galactic Peace!

([Read more here](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Nimbus_III))

Comment: ... and it turned out to be anything but. So, yes, this seems appropriate.

Answer (score -6):

### Room 42

A tribute to the late great Douglas Adams.

Answer (score -7):

### Hogwarts

[harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) is our top tag beside story-ID, and one that most of our users have at least some familiarity with. Plus, Hogwarts has always been a welcoming and homely place!

Answer (score -7):

[image]

**The Zócalo** is the central plaza and meeting place on the space station [Babylon 5](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page).  The goal of the Babylon 5 project was...

> *...to **prevent another war** by creating a place where humans and aliens **could work out their differences peacefully**. It's a port of call - **home away from home** for diplomats, hustlers, entrepreneurs, and wanderers. Humans and aliens wrapped in two million, five hundred thousand tons of spinning metal, all alone in the night.*

Comment: I don't even know how to spell this one.

Comment: @Wikis: The Zócalo!  :-)

Comment: @Wiki : No worries.  Refresh the answer and you'll see!  :-)

Answer (score -7):

## Praxis

I know it's a hopeless proposal, but I feel I should point that *praxis* holds a suitable meaning and that [it's used in many scifi works](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/99721/3823).

Plus it would be cool to have @Praxis owning Praxis.  That would embody the meaning of *praxis* (putting theory into practice).

This metapost is very meta.

Comment: Clearly the best proposal.

Comment: Praxis blew up. So, yes, this seems appropriate.

Answer (score -8):

## The Jedi Temple

Keeping with the [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) theme, a place for learning to occur.

Answer (score -8):

### Biers

Ankh-Morporkian pub where various "people" can show their true forms and nobody will give a second glance. Perhaps one of the few locations where, when asking the bartender for a Bloody Mary, he won't mix you simply a metaphor... Clientele include vampires, werewolves, zombies, bogeymen, ghouls, Tooth Fairies, and Mrs Gammage.

Comment: Yay, my renaming idea has approval from a mod! :-)

Comment: Yeah I liked the concept (bar for a bunch of mismatched characters) more than the name.

Comment: Given recent events, "The Broken Drum" seems like a better name.

Answer (score -8):

The Dark Tower

After the Stephen King novel that brings together several of his other sci-fi and fantasy characters together. Seems fitting.